# How to store UTC time values in Mongo with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

The behavior I'm observing with the Mongoid adapter is that it'll save 'time' fields with the current system timezone into the database.  Note that it's the system time and not Rail's environment's Time.zone.  If I change the system timezone, then subsequent saves will pick up the current system timezone.

```
# system currently at UTC -7
@record.time_attribute = Time.now.utc
@record.save

# in mongo, the value is "time_attribute" : "Mon May 17 2010 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (QYZST)"
@record.reload.time_attribute.utc?  # false
```

Comment: Which fields have you define for time_attributes ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can set the operating system date to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `use_utc` mongoid config parameter to `true`.

It tells Mongoid that you want to return times in UTC:
http://github.com/durran/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/config.rb#L22